# Django User.set_password leads to invalid password

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users

I'm trying to write a serializer (in Django REST Framework) to update a user's account details. Here is the update() method:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    ...
    if all([item in self.validated_data for item in ["password", "confirm_password", "old_password"]]):
        user = authenticate(username=self.context["request"].user.username, password=self.validated_data["old_password"])
        if user is not None:
            if self.validated_data["password"] == self.validated_data["confirm_password"]:
                validate_password(self.validated_data["password"])
                user.set_password(self.validated_data["password"])
                user.save()
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"confirm_password": "Passwords do not match"})
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"old_password": "Password incorrect"})

    self.validated_data.pop("password")

    return super(UserInfoSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

When I perform a PATCH request to the view with "password", "confirm_password" and "old_password" as fields, it appears to have worked. Then when I try to log into the account again, it fails (using both old and new passwords). When I check the admin settings and view the user I am trying to edit, I get the following:

> **Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.**
>
> Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user's
>   password, but you can change the password using this form.

I believe User.set_password() is supposed to handle hashing/etc. automatically, so why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deleted `password` from `self.validated_data` but not from `validated_data` dict which passed to superclass's `update` method. Try this:

```
validated_data.pop("password") # remove self, just leave validated_data

return super(UserInfoSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested in using my code, here is the final working code:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    ...
    if all([item in validated_data for item in ["password", "confirm_password", "old_password"]]):
        user = authenticate(username=instance.username, password=validated_data["old_password"])
        if user is not None and user == instance:
            if validated_data["password"] == validated_data["confirm_password"]:
                validate_password(validated_data["password"])
                instance.set_password(validated_data["password"])
                instance.save()  # change the password on the current instance object, otherwise changes will be overwritten
                login(self.context["request"], instance)  # without this line, the user is auto-logged out upon changing their password
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"confirm_password": "Passwords do not match"})
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"old_password": "Password incorrect"})

    if "password" in validated_data:
        validated_data.pop("password")

    return super(UserInfoSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```